# Block after if(false) is executed

Tags: java, netbeans

I hava a java project and when I try to debug this project I have a problem. All the blocks after if(false) condition are executed and the blocks after if(true) are not. For example:
[image]

As you can see I am in debug mode and line 65 is executed and line 61 is not executed.

If I do:

```
boolean trueValue = Boolean.TRUE;
boolean falseValue = Boolean.FALSE;

if(trueValue) {
    System.out.println("True");
}
if(falseValue) {
    System.out.println("False");
}
```

Both blockes are executed.

Something very strange is happening. After build I decompiled the compiled classes and the code is ok(For the fist example in the compiled class I have just the line "System.out.println("True");" and that is ok).

I am using Glassfish server, Java 7 and Netbeans. I reinstalled the netbeans, restarted the windows, build, clean the project. If I make a new project in Netbeans and I copy paste the examples above everything is ok.

Can somenone advice me?

Comment: refresh the deployed code, that's not possible.

Comment: Do a clean build. The code with `if (false)` causes an unreachable code error, and a subsequent debugging will go on old compiled code.

Comment: And re your example with `Boolean.TRUE` and `Boolean.FALSE`. **No**, they are not both executed: http://ideone.com/J85NRN Just the true one, as one would expect.

Comment: As I mentioned this is happening just in this project if I make a new one everything works normally.

Comment: @JoopEggen as you can see in the picture attached unreachable code is after if(true), look at the debug break point.

Comment: The `.class` file that you're running wasn't built from the `.java` file that you're stepping through.  You need to do a clean build.

Comment: The debugging is done with old code shown in the new source, hence the debugger shows wrong lines. There is no new code compiled, as there were compilation errors with `if (false)`: unreachable code. This is an error in javac. A clean build should show that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved after I installed again glassfish server.